# How can I fix a corrupted usb on windows 10?

Tags: windows, boot, usb, partitioning

My story is different and huge please help me.

Yesterday I removed my entire windows 10  from my Acer PC (it was infected with a virus named Win32/Floxif.H which infected all the files in my PC) and now it says " No bootable device found "

I borrowed my dad's pc and downloaded Windows 10 ISO and installed rufus from https://rufus.ie which creates bootable pendrive from an ISO file.

But the problem is the USB pendrive has gone mad or corrupted if I use rufus to create a bootable USB it shows some error so I decide to use software to format USB like minitool partition wizard, easeus paartition, some others and finally all fail and give error.

I then tried to use the command prompt diskpart and even that fails again then I try formatting from explorer , and found a hint that the USB formats successfully but only in FAT32 file system other formats like NTFS give error so the problem is the USB cannot be converted to any other formats other except FAT32 so rufus fails to create a bootable device and when I enter into the USB in FAT32 format it has a folder with name "System Volume Information" according to me there is some important info in that folder which windows has created and is preventing from formatting into other formats.

Comment: If you have access to a Windows computer why do you think you need Rufus anyway? Better to use the default and official Windows Media Creation tool.

Answer (score 2):

That flash drive is dead. Bin it and buy a new one.

Rufus FAQ has a long section titled ["Help, Rufus damaged my flash drive!"](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_Rufus_damaged_my_flash_drive). If you don't want to read it in its entirety, here's a short excerpt:

> So, unless you have been running bad blocks checks for days, I have to be very categoric that your drive was not damaged by Rufus. Whatever damage you maybe believe has been incurred while you were using Rufus is either a detection issue or a **standard hardware failure** due to normal wear and tear, that just happened to coincide with when Rufus was accessing your drive. Obviously, when you use something, there's always a risk it will independently choose that moment to fail. But you can rest assured that your drive would have failed the exact same way, had you been copying a large file using Windows Explorer, instead of using Rufus.